# Multiple error messages for one input field

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I am creating a form using facelets. One input field looks like this:

```
<p:inputText id="initials" value="#{dilution.initials}" />
```

`dilution` is a entity bean and the initials field has two validation constraints set on it. One size constraint and one regex pattern constraint. My problem is getting error messages for both constraints to display next to the input field. Using the `<h:message>` only display one of the messages and using `<h:messages>` displays all input fields error messages or nothing (when I tried setting `<h:messages for="initials" autoUpdate="true" />`).

Is there any simple way to do this?

The full form:

```
<h:form id="addDilForm">
    <p:panel>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="TRUE" />
    <p:panelGrid>
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <p:row><p:column colspan="3">Ny spädningsfaktor</p:column></p:row>
        </f:facet>

        <p:row> 
            <p:column colspan="1">
                <p:outputLabel for="sampT">Provtyp</p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="sampT" required="true" value="#{dilution.dilution.sampleType.ID}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{SampleTypeController.samples}" var="samp" itemLabel="#{samp.name}" itemValue="#{samp.ID}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:message for="sampT" />
            </p:column>                                        
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel for="initials">Initialer</p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column >
                <p:inputText id="initials" value="#{dilution.initials}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:message for="initials" />
            </p:column>                                  
        </p:row>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="3">
                    <p:commandButton  value="Save" action="#{dilution.save()}" update="addDilForm" icon="ui-icon-check" />                                
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Using the `<h:message>` only display one of the messages*

Just use `<h:messages>` with the plural "s" instead of `<h:message>` while keeping the `for` attribute.

```
<h:messages for="initials" />
```

The `<p:messages>` works the same way, only with a different UI.

Comment: I tried this but nothing was displayed at all. That is I put `<p:messages for="initials" />` at the place where I now have `<p:message for="initials" />`. Do I need to set/change something else inorder for it to work?

Comment: Okey, I see it works for `<h:messages>` but not `<p:messages>`, when I try it. But I would like to use `<p:messages>`, should that be possible?